# identity framekwork: how to get current login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile files)
        {   
            //var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            //var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            //var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(_userManager.GetUserId(Request.HttpContext.User));
            //var user = User.Identity.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);  _userManager.GetUserId(Request.HttpContext.User);
            //var user1 = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
            //var userId = user?.Id; 
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var stream = files.OpenReadStream();
            var name = files.FileName;
            byte[] fileData = ReadFully(stream);            
            return Content("Error in uploads");

        }
```

I have this action method. I have created login action whose result is success.
I am trying to get the ID of the current login user but im not able to get that. I have tried 50 ways to do that but failing again and again.

help needed
thanks in adv

Comment: You've tried 50 ways, but for none you mention how it failed. There is far too little information in your question, if you really want some help. Please read this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it's propably because your user is not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add HttpContext.user

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
if (user == null) return View("Error");
```

Comment: I think he didn't try anything. There is no actual code, just some commented lines.

Comment: Sounds like its not reading the cookie properly do you have [authorize] set at the top of your controller?